# connection not getting created to the new dbname in mongoengine

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

Using python Mongoengine I am trying to create databases and add documents to different databases. Here's how I am trying to do it :

```
from mongoengine import *

class MongoDataAccessObject():
    # method to connect to the database and initialize the tables etc.
    def __init__(self, my_env, helperObj):
        print "initializing db for the environment ", my_env
        self.con = None
        self.dbName = my_env
        self.helper_obj = helperObj

        try:
            self.con = connect(db=self.dbName)
        except Exception as e:
            print e

     def addRecord(self, document_object):
         document_object.save()
```

Now, I pass the names of different databases that I want created while creating the object of the above class, and add the documents like this :

```
for my_env in list_of_envs:
        dao = MongoDataAccessObject(my_env, helper_object)
        dao.addRecord(myDocument)
```

Now there are 2 questions here:

1. For some reason all my documents keep getting added to the same DB (the first one being passed while MongoDataAccessObject object creation. I would assume that when I am creating a new object every time, while passing a different db name each time, a new connection should get created to the new db passed and documents should get added to the db which is currently connected to.
2. To verify if I am actually connected to the DB in question or not, I could not find a method like get_database_name() on the connection object. Is there a way to verify if I am getting connected to the DB name being passed or not ?

Ok did some more research and found this:
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/605

Tried it out like this in iptyhon:

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

class Page(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

def switch(model, db):
    model._meta['db_alias'] = db
    # must set _collection to none so it is re-evaluated
    model._collection = None
    return model

register_connection('default', name='testing')
register_connection('mycon', name='db1')
page = Page(title="Test Page")
page = switch(page, 'mycon')
page.save()
```

This works and creates a db named db1 and stores the document there.

Now I do this again:

```
register_connection('mycon2', name='db2')
page = Page(title="Test Page")
page = switch(page, 'mycon2')
page.save()
```

Contrary to my expectation this time db2 was not created (checked from both mongo client and from Robomongo), however the document was saved successfully. Wonder where exactly did the document get saved then ??

So to figure that out repeated the above exercise with a small change as below:

```
register_connection('mycon2', name='db2')
page = Page(title="Test Page")
page = switch(page, 'mycon2')
x = page.save()
# did a dir(x) and found that there is _get_db, so tried it out as below
x._get_db()
```

and the output was :

> Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary()), u'db2')

which I guess means that the document got saved in a database named db2. But where on earth is this db2 ???? Why can't I see it through either mongo client or even Robomongo etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the only way I could find to achieve the above was through the context manager *with* statement provided by MongoEngine, which also is well documented here : http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#switch-database

The way I did it in my code above is something like this :

In the first call to the db, a default db needs to be created, which should have the alias as default. Only then can another alias be created, else Mongoengine throws an error saying that no default db found.

So to do this, when the very first db object is created, a False flag is sent to the *__init__of MongoDataAccessObject*
So to do this, the MongoDataAccessObject was also changed to something like this:

```
class MongoDataAccessObject():
    # method to connect to the database and initialize the tables etc.
    def __init__(self, my_env, helperObj, is_default_db_set):
        print "initializing db for the environment ", my_env
        self.con = None
        self.dbName = my_env
        self.helper_obj = helperObj
        self.db_alias = my_env
        self.is_default_db_set = is_default_db_set

        try:
            # all of this part with the is_default_db_set  and register_connection() is needed because MongoEngine does not 
            # provide a simple way of changing dbs or switching db connections. The only way to do it is through the switch_db()
            # context manager they provide (which has been used in the addRecord() below)
            if not self.is_default_db_set:
                self.con = connect(db=self.dbName, alias='default')
            else:
                # register_connection(alias_name, db_name)
                register_connection(self.db_alias, self.dbName)

        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

And the *addRecord()* was also modified as :

```
def addRecord(self, document_object):
         with switch_db(model_object, self.db_alias) as model_object:
                 document_object = model_object()
                 document_object.save()
```

And this part above:

```
for my_env in list_of_envs:
        dao = MongoDataAccessObject(my_env, helper_object)
        dao.addRecord(myDocument)
```

was also modified as:

```
for my_env in list_of_envs:
        dao = MongoDataAccessObject(my_env,helper_object,mongo_default_db_flag)
        dao.addRecord(myDocument)
```

And this seemed to do the job for me.